# Factorial Anova in R

Tags: r, anova

I am trouble understanding summary of factorial anova in R.
I don't understand why I am getting Df of 2 for only the first variable. A,B,C and D all have 3 levels so in my understanding I should get 2 Df for those and interaction of those.
Please help me to fix the code or understand the results.

P.S. Where can I find the list of options for summary()? I saw one example that removed the * after sig level and I want to see what options I have.

Thank you in advance

Here is Data I have

Complete data set I have

```
 Runs I  A  B  C  D AB  E AD BC  F  G  H  J  K B1 B2     y
1     1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 190.9
2     2 1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 436.2
3     3 1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 480.3
4     4 1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 406.3
5     5 1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 212.9
6     6 1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 478.7
7     7 1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 396.5
8     8 1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 349.7
9     9 1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 119.7
10   10 1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 372.2
11   11 1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 411.6
12   12 1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 382.8
13   13 1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 161.2
14   14 1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 424.3
15   15 1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 322.8
16   16 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 302.1
17   17 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0 302.4
18   18 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0 318.2
19   19 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0 332.8

> data
###Factors
> A
 [1] -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  0  0  0 
Levels: -1 0 1
> B
 [1] -1 -1 1  1  -1 -1 1  1  -1 -1 1  1  -1 -1 1  1  0  0  0 
Levels: -1 0 1
> C
 [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 1  1  1  1  -1 -1 -1 -1 1  1  1  1  0  0  0 
Levels: -1 0 1
> D
 [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0 
Levels: -1 0 1

####Response variable
> data$y
 [1] 190.9 436.2 480.3 406.3 212.9 478.7 396.5 349.7 119.7 372.2 411.6 382.8 161.2 424.3 322.8 302.1 302.4 318.2
[19] 332.8

A=as.factor(data$A)
B=as.factor(data$B)
C=as.factor(data$C)
D=as.factor(data$D)



out3=lm(data$y~C+B+A+D)
fit1=aov(out3)
summary(fit1)

> summary(fit1)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
C            2   2743    1372   0.170 0.8456  
B            1  26896   26896   3.332 0.0910 .
A            1  45839   45839   5.679 0.0331 *
D            1  12928   12928   1.602 0.2279  
Residuals   13 104934    8072
```

Same anova with different order of variable

> summary(fit1)
>                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
>       B            2  28199   14100   1.747 0.2129
>       A            1  45839   45839   5.679 0.0331 *
>       D            1  12928   12928   1.602 0.2279
>       C            1   1440    1440   0.178 0.6796
>       Residuals   13 104934    8072

If I conduct anova with only 2 levels(exclude 0 for all variables, and use [1:16] data only since last 3 data are based on "0" level ), then it comes out fine. I get Df of 1 for all var but residuals.

Comment: I think this must be related to the fact that the resulting model matrix is not of full rank, meaning that there is linear dependency between the dummy variables of the 4 factors. Can you provide some more details about the factorial design?

Comment: I added complete data set and another anova with different order of variable. I tried multiple things but I keep getting Df of 2 for only the first variable.

Comment: Please give some more details about your factorial design (e.g., full or fractional factorial, number of factors, number of levels per factor etc...)! Somehow, it seems to me as if you might be mixing up the original factors with their dummy variables, but I can only know for sure if I get more details about the factorial design.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. So it is 2^4 frac factorial design with some confounding. Originally I have ABCD. A-H are measurement var and JK are qualitative var. B1 and B2 are blocking. I screened some out so I only left with A,B,C,D,AB and BC. All vars now have 3 levels.

Comment: So EFGHJK B1 B2 are confounded with some interaction var between ABCD.

Comment: I don't really get it. So it's a 2^4 fractional factorial design, but each factor has 3 levels? I think this should make it a 3^(4-k) FrF design. I think you should first try to gain more insight into your design and potential aliasing. Perhaps you might find an answer along the way. Besides, I don't think stackoverflow is the right forum to further discuss this issue, as it seems to me this is a more theoretical issue that goes beyond programming issues. Anyhow, what LyzandeR has suggested is correct, but it just comes down to the linear dependency I have suggested in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying and thinking and thinking and saying how could this be possible that the degrees of freedom are not calculated correctly? But sometimes we only think about complicated things and forget about the easy things. I found what the problem is:

```
data <- read.table(header=T,text='Runs I  A  B  C  D AB  E AD BC  F  G  H  J  K B1 B2     y
1     1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 190.9
2     2 1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 436.2
3     3 1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 480.3
4     4 1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1 406.3
5     5 1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 212.9
6     6 1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 478.7
7     7 1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  1 396.5
8     8 1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 349.7
9     9 1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 119.7
10   10 1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 372.2
11   11 1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 411.6
12   12 1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 382.8
13   13 1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 161.2
14   14 1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 424.3
15   15 1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 322.8
16   16 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 302.1
17   17 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0 302.4
18   18 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0 318.2
19   19 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0 332.8')

a.dummies <- model.matrix(~A)
b.dummies <- model.matrix(~B)
c.dummies <- model.matrix(~C)
d.dummies <- model.matrix(~D)


a<-cbind(a.dummies[,-1],b.dummies[,-1])
b<-cbind(c.dummies[,-1],d.dummies[,-1])
all<-cbind(a,b)
```

I took the liberty to create the dummies on my own to check them one by one. And the problem revealed itself.
Simple correlation table:

> cor(all)

```
           A0         A1         B0         B1         C0         C1         D0         D1
A0  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745
A1 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636
B0  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745
B1 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636
C0  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745
C1 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  0.1363636
D0  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745  1.0000000 -0.3692745
D1 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  0.1363636 -0.3692745  1.0000000
```

The way the lm function works (and many more model functions) is to eliminate one of two variables that have a correlation of exactly 1 i.e. remove duplicate columns. In your case C0 has a correlation of 1 against A0, B0 and D0 so those 3 were removed from the model effectively reducing the number of levels of your factors to 2 for A,B and D. Therefore, the degrees of freedom are now 1 for A, B and D.

Mystery solved!!!

Comment: And just because you are new to the site I would like to say that if one answer solves your question (and only then) please do mark it as accepted (by clicking the tick next to the answer) so that other users who have the same problem might be helped in the future. Accepting an answer will give both you and the person who answered, reputation. Gaining reputation will allow you to make better use of the site by unlocking privileges. I am always saying this to new users :). Welcome to SO! P.S. (accepting an answer is not compulsory)

Comment: Thanks a lot!. But I think I still have problem... I were to do anova with all 19 data points with 3 replicates. I now think that I may not understand statistics correctly than using R. Here is the exact question that I should answer: Use ANOVA to estimate the model without the inactive factors. Include the center point runs for this step. From this model, use ANOVA F test to determine the significant effects. You should generate diagnostic plots of residual, including a normal probability plot.

Comment: That is a totally different question. You can ask that as a separate question on SO or on Cross Validated if it is only for stats. If the answer above has answered your initial question, about the degrees of freedom feel free to accept to help future people with the same problem. Otherwise, please explain why you didn't like the answer.

Comment: And generally asking homework questions like the above comment as it is, is not forbidden but it is frowned upon by most of the users.

Comment: Ok. I am not saying I didn't like the answer but it just seems that my problem is not exactly solved. So do you mean if I keep replicates in my model, I am not able to get correct ANOVA? I am looking for the way to get Anova with all 19 data. I was thinking that I was supposed to get Df of 2 for every variable with 3 levels.

Comment: But this is the correct model and this is the correct ANOVA. Using duplicate columns in your regression is simply wrong. And all of the dummy variables that are created do have 19 records. It is only the duplicate columns that get eliminated. Getting 2 degrees of freedom for each variable with this kind of data is impossible but not because this is wrong. This is actually the way it is supposed to work!

Comment: If I were you I would explain the above to my teacher. They should really understand, and if they wanted you to have 2 dof they should provide different data. The ANOVA table is just as it should be!